# Problems with the method setChoiceMode () in my ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, listviewitem

Please note, this is really weird.

For some reason, the method setChoiceMode (ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) no results.

I use it like this:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
list.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListenerObject);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The fact is that after I put the method setChoiceMode (), nothing has changed, RadioButtons not appeared. 
I'm using a custom adapter and I have no problems with it? But I do not understand why Radiobuttons not shown.

Any ideas? (If you need additional code, ask and I'll post it.)

My adapter code:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
private View view;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contacts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private Contact getContact(int position) {
    return (Contact) getItem(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
    }

    Contact c = getContact(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_name)).setText(c.getName() + " " + c.getSurname());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_img)).setImageBitmap(c.getPhoto());

    return view;
}
}
```

Below shows the layout that I use for ListView item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lv_img"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_user"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What class you extend from?

Comment: MyActivity extend ActionBarActivity and MyAdapter extend BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Setting the choice mode does not automatically make radio buttons appear. All it does is add behavior which toggles a `ListView` row's `Checkable` or activation state.  It's still up to the row's `View` to decide how to react to that.  You'll need to create your own layout to inflate for a row that supports the activation state or the Checkable interface.

Android does provide some simple pre-made views that you can use. Here's just a couple you can choose from:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1.xml
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked.xml
```

Comment: How do I use it in my adapter?

Comment: How should I fix my adapter to make it work. (I post my adapter code)